# Automatically include group/version/kind in serialized Kubernetes resource?

Tags: go, kubernetes, serialization

Given code like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"

    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/serializer/json"
    "k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/scheme"
)

func main() {
    corev1.AddToScheme(scheme.Scheme)

    serializer := json.NewSerializerWithOptions(
        json.DefaultMetaFactory, scheme.Scheme, scheme.Scheme,
        json.SerializerOptions{
            Pretty: true,
            Yaml:   true,
            Strict: true,
        })

    namespace := corev1.Namespace{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: "example",
        },
    }
    if err := serializer.Encode(&namespace,
        os.Stdout); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get the serialized output to include the kind and api group/version other than providing it manually? As written, the above code produces:

```yaml
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: example
spec: {}
status: {}
```

When what I want is:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: example
spec: {}
status: {}
```

I realize I can do this:

```golang
namespace := corev1.Namespace{
    TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{
        Kind:       "Namespace",
        APIVersion: "v1",
    },
    ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
        Name: "example",
    },
}
```

But it seems like all the necessary metadata exists to produce this information without me having to provide it explicitly (that is, I'm already creating a `corev1.Namespace` object; shouldn't the g/v/k be derived directly from this type?).

Answer (score 1):

This can be a bit trickier than expected. The reason is that you should NOT assume that there's only a single GVK for each Kubernetes struct. This re-usage it's more common for internal unversioned types.

That being said, you can do something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"

    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/serializer/json"
)

func main() {
    scheme := runtime.NewScheme()
    corev1.AddToScheme(scheme)

    serializer := json.NewSerializerWithOptions(
        json.DefaultMetaFactory, scheme, scheme,
        json.SerializerOptions{
            Pretty: true,
            Yaml:   true,
            Strict: true,
        })

    namespace := corev1.Namespace{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: "example",
        },
    }

    gvks, isUnversioned, err := scheme.ObjectKinds(&namespace)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if !isUnversioned && len(gvks) == 1 {
        namespace.TypeMeta = metav1.TypeMeta{
            Kind:       gvks[0].Kind,
            APIVersion: gvks[0].GroupVersion().Identifier(),
        }
    }
    if err := serializer.Encode(&namespace,
        os.Stdout); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Note that you're mutating the `namespace` variable by attributing the TypeMeta. If you don't want that, you'll need to do `namespace.DeepCopy()` first before encoding it.